# Akka - assign dispatcher to an actor based on name pattern

Tags: configuration, akka

I need to assign a custom dispatcher to a bunch of actors based on their name pattern.
The name pattern is this: `OptimizationManager-{id}` where id is a variable. I tried to use the same approach as in ActorSelection where I can use a wildcard `*`:

```
akka {
  actor {
    optimization-manager-dispatcher {
      type = Dispatcher
      executor = "fork-join-executor"
    }

    deployment {
        "/OptimizationManager-*" {
            dispatcher = akka.actor.optimization-manager-dispatcher 
        }
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work. In the logs I still see that OptimizatinManagers use default-dispatcher. Is it possible to achieve what I need in the configuration file? I know that the last resort is to do it in the code using `Props.withDispatcher`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html#actor-deployment-configuration) explicitly state you cannot :

> You can use asterisks as wildcard matches for the actor path sections,
>   so you could specify: `/*/sampleActor` and that would match all
>   sampleActor on that level in the hierarchy. You can also use wildcard
>   in the last position to match all actors at a certain level:
>   `/someParent/*`. Non-wildcard matches always have higher priority to
>   match than wildcards, so: `/foo/bar` is considered more specific than
>   `/foo/*` and only the highest priority match is used. **Please note that
>   it cannot be used to partially match section, like this: `/foo*/bar`,
>   /f*o/bar etc.**

I'm afraid your `/OptimizationManager-*` is considered a partial match.